# extension of a different article of that same question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[Find the intersection of two parametric equations at one point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132334/find-the-intersection-of-two-parametric-equations-at-one-point)

is basically the question.

So, I need to find the sum of $k$ (which isn't written in that link). For the values of $k$ @MvG listed: $- 3 \pm2\sqrt{6}, -3 \pm 2\sqrt{2}$, all I have to do is add them together to get my final answer?

Comment: Please use LaTeX format

Comment: Yes, if you need to find their sum, you only need to add them. On the other hand, If you still haven't solved the quadratic equations at the end, then stop and don't solve them yet. If $x_1,x_2$ are the solutions of $ax^2+bx+c=0$, then $-b/a=x_1+x_2$. Therefore, you only need to add the $-b/a$ for the two equations they got: $-6 + (-6)=-12$.